# Seeking GIS tool to automatically extract polygon geometries from images

Tags: geometry, software-recommendations, image, vectorization, feature-extraction

Let's say I have multiple `png` images like the following one:

[image]

I'd like to find a way where I can automatically draw polygon geometries on this image. Something like the following:

[image]

My expectation is to give an image as input and have an output with something like a GeoJSON (or any other geospatial format that I can convert to GeoJSON later).  The positions could be in a relative position to one of the corner points of my image. But by now I have no idea what kind of tool I could use for that.

Are there any Python libraries, JavaScript libraries, or alternative tools that I can use for this purpose?

Comment: A possibility is to use an image processing software (like Photoshop, Affinity Photo, GIMP) to make a selection and than enhance contrast or even convert it to a black/white image, preserving only the shapes. Then import/georeference this image to QGIS and create contour polygons with the GDAL provider - see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/384564/88814

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/415097/classifying-raster-layer-by-number-of-equal-values-in-given-area-using-qgis/415099#415099

Comment: For software recommendations there is the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 5):

GlobalMapper [Blue Marble] can do the extraction quickly.

Using your image here is an example using the Equal Value extraction. and choosing 'pick from map' and using the sampler tool to create area from the raster.

If you know the area (coordinate system) the image can be geo-referenced before doing this extraction and the data would be in the correct position.

A software trial can be used for your own testing.
https://www.bluemarblegeo.com/global-mapper/

[image]

Comment: In this case, the trial version can be used for an amount of time and then I'd have to buy a lifetime license of $599? Or this value has to be paid every month?

Comment: Single User (Node-Locked) License for 1 year +support +training etc.. (Floating licenses are more expensive but good if your have a bigger team.) For full info I would contact the vendor.